# Excluding an imaginary, partial, part of solution from Solve

Tags: syntax

When I type the command

```
Solve[{x + 1/x == y - 1/y, x^2 + 1/x^2 == y^2 - 1/y^2}] // Simplify // N
```

I get a 'close to zero' imaginary part, `2.77556*10^-17 I`,  that really should not be included in the answer. How can I instruct `Solve` to only return (partial) real answers when the imaginary part is 'close to zero' or 'less than $\epsilon$'? Using `Reals` returned, understandably, `{}` as the $x$:s are imaginary, but not the $y$:s. TIA. (I'm using Mathematica 11.2.0.0, perhaps this 'should be zero'-problem has been corrected in later versions.)

Comment: Apply `Chop` to the result: `Solve[...]//N//Chop` or `NSolve[...]//Chop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve) instead of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) followed by N:

```
NSolve[{x + 1/x == y - 1/y, x^2 + 1/x^2 == y^2 - 1/y^2}]
```

> {{x -> -0.353553 - 0.935414 I, y -> 0.707107}, {x -> -0.353553 + 0.935414 I, 
>     y -> 0.707107}, {x -> 0.353553 - 0.935414 I, 
>     y -> -0.707107}, {x -> 0.353553 + 0.935414 I, y -> -0.707107}}

Or, you can use [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) instead of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify):

```
Solve[{x + 1/x == y - 1/y, x^2 + 1/x^2 == y^2 - 1/y^2}] // FullSimplify // N
```

> {{x -> -0.353553 + 0.935414 I, y -> 0.707107}, {x -> 0.353553 - 0.935414 I, 
>     y -> -0.707107}, {x -> -0.353553 - 0.935414 I, 
>     y -> 0.707107}, {x -> 0.353553 + 0.935414 I, y -> -0.707107}}

Comment: The `FullSimplify` gives those `Root` expressions in Mathematica 11.2.0.0 when excluding the `N`. Perhaps this is solved in recent version?